# Using ImageProcessingLog in AForge library

Tags: c#, image-processing, aforge

I have a sample program from `Aforge` library. It uses a kind of logging system (I assume it is like a `StringBuilder` or something...).

In the samples, here and there I see something like:

```
IImageProcessingLog _log = new ImageProcessingLog();

//some code
_log.AddMessage("Image size: " + _bitmap.Width + " x " + _bitmap.Height);
//more codes and usage of `_log`
```

Clearly this is some sort of string. Later I want to dump all this data into a `TextBox`. I tried to do `_log.ToString()` but it just returns the object name.

Any idea how can I use this log feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ImageProcessingLog` class has a property called `Messages`.
`Messages` is of type `List<string>`. So, to get all logged messages
simply iterate the elements of the messages list.

```
TextBox tbMessages = ...;

ImageProcessingLog log = new ImageProcessingLog();

log.AddMessage(...);

foreach(string msg in log.Messages)
{
  tbMessages.Text += msg;      
}
```

Unfortunately the `IImageProcessingLog` interface does not have such a property.
A possible workaround would be to create an adapter class/interface which wraps the
`ImageProcessingLog` class.